# Как отключить скрипт (плагин) на домашней странице?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Требуется отключить один плагин №1 и его скрипты только на главной странице, чтобы он не мешал отображению контента.

чтобы отключить скрипты плагина№2 который ломает код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрипты в плагинах подключаются через функцию wp_enqueue_script(), где указывается название скрипта, которое, как правило, должно быть уникальным. Соответственно для отключения можно использовать функцию wp_deregister_script() с указанием названия скрипта и обернуть это все в условие для главной is_home():

```
if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
    function remove_script() {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery'); // jQuery в качестве примера
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_script');
}
```

Данный код можно вставить в файл темы functions.php

Comment: если я не ошиблась с названием плагина то вышел такой итоговый вариант  if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
    function remove_script() {
        wp_deregister_script('o2-master'); // jQuery в качестве примера
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_script');
} и он не сработал

Comment: @Chernikova название плагина тут ни при чем. Надо смотреть код плагина, искать в нем wp_enqueue_script(), в них имена (handle) скриптов. И удалять через wp_dequeue_script(). Таких скриптов может быть довольно много. Кроме того, функцию remove_script() надо запускать с приоритетом меньшим, чем запуск скриптов в плагине, чтобы она сработала раньше и успела отменить скрипты плагина. Обычно, приоритета 5 достаточно. Строка подключения должна выглядеть примерно так: `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_script', 5);`

Comment: данный вариант может сработать, но его действительно придется долго делать чтобы найти все скрипты чтобы отключить. засчитаю таки как подходящий вариант, этот ответ

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wVXskAAC получился довольно длинный код, однако плагину пофиг и его скрипты все равно работают

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать плагин [Plugin Organizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-organizer/). Он позволяет отключать любые плагины на любых страницах.

Comment: я рассматривала его, но так и не поняла как отключить в нем плагин на определенной странице. я использовала еще этот плагин https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-load-filter/ он более понятен, однако с задачей справился плохо

Comment: Разбирайтесь, он работает. Я использовал его на нескольких сайтах

Comment: важно с какими темами а не на скольких сайтах. тема Р2 breathe которая работает совместно с плагином о2. попробуйте этот тетрис

Comment: Неважно, с какими темами. Работает с любыми. Другое дело, насколько связаны ваша и тема, плагин и код страницы вашего сайта. Страница может и упасть с кодом 500 после отключения плагина

Comment: данная тема с этим плагином связаны на 100% . было бы проще отключить плагин и проблема решена. но решена она для других тем, а не для Р2 темы. у нее слетает сразу большая часть стилей и функций без этого плагина.